# Tapestry 5 + log4j2

Tags: spring, logging, slf4j, log4j2, tapestry

Has somebody ever tried to use default built in slf4j with log4j2 in Tapestry 5.4?
I can use the log4j2 like this:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
...    
private Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(this.getClass());
```

But I can not use like this:

```
import org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.annotations.Inject; 
import org.slf4j.Logger;
... 
@Inject private Logger logger;
```

I can not understand why, because I think, I added to my gradle script the 
required libs:

```
runtime group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.8'
runtime group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.8'
runtime group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-web', version: '2.8'
runtime group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-slf4j-impl', version: '2.8'
```

Has anyone any idea, why does it not work for me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there any errors? How do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: Hi!
Thanks for the reply. The problem was that in the log4j2.xml was set the min level DEBUG but if use the inject version, only logging in info level, but if I use this `private Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(this.getClass());` then DEBUG level was on.

Anyway my co-worker helped me out, I 'm going to answer the solution. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was helped out, and I found a solution, I had to change the gradle file to this:

```
compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.8'
compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.8'
compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-web', version: '2.8'
compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-slf4j-impl', version: '2.8'
```